# Update another table field using data macro on open database

Tags: ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaT4Q.png)I have date in tblMyTable and would like to update the same date to another table tblMyTableNew using data macro. This would update date field on database open. Could you please help with this issue.

Comment: Data Macro cannot do this. Try an AutoExec macro. Build an UPDATE action query object and have macro run it. I never use macros. I prefer VBA behind a form set to open by default. Frankly, requirement does not make sense.

Comment: Date in tblMyTable is set with data macro on open database automatically from difference of two dates where that difference has to be more than 48 hours. When I open form I see that date in a form but I want that date to be updated to another table when it appears in tblMyTableNew also on open database using data macro beacuse I can set RunDataMacro in Autoexec macro.

Comment: Okay, I knew about RunMacro but not RunDataMacro. So if you already know about this method, exactly what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry you are right RunMacro

Comment: When hours are bigger than 48 hours I get date1 in tblMyTable and that is working fine. Then when database is not in use date1 may appear in tblMyTable after 48 hours when condition is met. Is it possible to create Named Data Macro to update date1 to tblMyTableNew date field. If is possible than I would put that Named Data Macro to Autoexec to run automatically on database open.

Comment: Possibly, and I already made a rough suggestion - but as already stated I would use VBA. Make attempt and when you have code (macro or VBA) with issue, post question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is ok to use VBA but I am a beginner and do not know VBA that well.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of AfterUpdate Data macro

Comment: You should edit your question to include image, not create an answer. Does macro work?

Comment: No it does not work. Either update action query does not work because I want to update date for specific ID. If I put criteria in Query to include which ID to update then on open database asks me the ID

Comment: Why a specific ID? How would you identify which ID during open?